# AngularJS ng-model controller value not updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a bootstrap modal pop-up as per the documentation. In that pop-up I wish to have a simple select form where a user selects a value.

Extract of this:

```
<ng-form>
    <label for="hours">Hours</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="hours" ng-model="hours" ng-options="n for n in [1,max_hours] | makeRange" ng-value="n"></select>
</ng-form>

 @{{ hours }}
```

When I choose a new value in my drop down value, the hours displayed below it updates fine. However, when I go to get the value in my controller, it has not changed. I am new to angular so not too sure why this is.

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, time, date, max_hours) {

$scope.time = time;
$scope.date = date;
$scope.max_hours = max_hours;
$scope.hours = 1;

$scope.ok = function () {
    alert($scope.hours);
    $modalInstance.close({"date" : $scope.date, "time" : $scope.time, "hour" : $scope.hours});
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
  $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

};
```

The value in the alert always seems to be 1 (the initial value) regardless of the value displayed in the dropdown and the value displayed in the template. It is getting the value from the controller at the start correctly though, as if I change the initial hours value to 2 then the initial selected value will be 2.

Comment: Try to pass an object instead of primitive values since it could be a consequence of a directive creating a child scope.

Comment: please provide a plunkr or a jsfiddle